# DateFormat to hours and minutes from inside a list view

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am kinda find some difficulties on a project I am currently building. To help you understand I have the following screenshot.

[image: Join Opened League]

I retrieve the league's name and the date via a web service. The date represents when the league starts. Hence, League A starts next day at 11:00:50.

And here is how I retrieve those objects.

```
try {
                        if (response.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                            //getTeam(username, password);

                      JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("leagues");

                      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                showOpenLeagues = new   ShowOpenLeagues();

 JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                showOpenLeagues.setLeagueName(jsonObject1.getString("league_name"));
                                showOpenLeagues.setLeagueStart(jsonObject1.getString("league_start"));
                                showOpenLeagues.setLeagueId(jsonObject1.getString("ID"));
                                showOpenLeaguesList.add(showOpenLeagues);



                                listView.setAdapter(openLeaguesAdapter);


                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
```

Nothing more than parsing a json array.

Now here is my problem. I want to find a way of getting all those date formats and convert them to hours and minutes WITHOUT CLICKING IN ANY ROW!!!. I did something similar,but I displayed the timer(using the CountDownTimer class and its overridden methods) in a single textview which is much easier.

Thank you.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your source code. I strongly suspect that's not how it looks in your IDE - why would we want to see it with that broken indentation? (It's also not clear why you need such a huge screenshot where the bottom half of it is useless...)

Comment: _Converting them to hours and minutes_ does this mean `league a 11 : 00 league b 11 : 26`

Comment: If you're actually asking "how do I parse a string into a date/time object" then that's a much simpler question which doesn't need *any* screenshots, JSON etc...

Comment: I want something like this. "5h:23m" which represent the hours and minutes left.

Comment: and I put some code in here,because many people ask it. I have refactor it by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

As you are getting date in format

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

and you want it to format

```
HH:mm
```

do it like :

```
SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", java.util.Locale.getDefault());

try {
  Date parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
  String  outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);
} catch (Exception e) { 
}
```

now you have a string => outputDate that will only contain Hours and minutes.
There can be many combinations possible, i.e.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
```

Comment: This is what I did for a single textview as I mentioned. But in this case I have listview with its own adapter. Maybe I should put this code in the adapter?

Comment: I put  String leagueStart = showOpenLeaguesList.get(i).getLeagueStart(); inside the for loop so I can read each date in the list from the debugger:). Now I am ready to do the conversion:)

Comment: You put this code inside the getView() method or you can make a utils method that takes date in string, inputformat and outputformat then call it form get view to format the date